# How to draw a human character using Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to Cocos2d and was wondering if anyone can show me how to create a human character or any type of character using Cocos2d for my iphone app. Also show me how to get started with a maze would be helpful. THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iDevGames had a post recently about sources of free game assets that you may find useful:

http://www.idevgames.com/news/textures-brushes-models-free-game-assets

Answer (score 0):

You would typically draw your assets as images in something like Photoshop, and then import them as resources. You might be able to find a free set of graphics that will suit your needs if drawing isn't your forte, or if you're unable to spend money on a designer.